# Why does `polymorphic_allocator` take a `memory_resource` pointer and not a reference?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, allocator

The C++17 Standard says:

> [[mem.poly.allocator.ctor]](http://eel.is/c++draft/mem.poly.allocator.ctor)
>
> ```
> polymorphic_allocator(memory_resource* r);
> ```
>
> - *Requires:* `r` is non-null.
> - *Effects:* Sets `memory_­rsrc` to `r`.
> - *Throws:* Nothing.
> - [ *Note:* This constructor provides an implicit conversion from `memory_­resource*`. — *end note* ]

What's the point of accepting a `memory_resource*` instead of a `memory_resource&` if the *"requires"* clause mentions that `r` must be non-null?

The Bloomberg¹ style guide encourages accepting arguments that are going to be mutated by pointer instead of reference so that the ampersand on the caller side becomes a visual marker for mutation. However, there is no such precedent in the Standard.

**What is the reason that `r` is taken as a pointer and not as a reference?**

---

¹ `pmr` was standardized with heavy Bloomberg participation, as the company uses a polymorphic allocator model.

Comment: I think your note might indicate the reason. The design was heavily influenced by Bloomberg, but I can't personally say whether this aspect was contested in a meeting.

Comment: A guess: consistency with `[io]stream`s that take `streambuf` pointer. These are the only other entities in `std` I can think of that are a similar kind of non-owning interface adapter.

Comment: @chris: I just found it weird that this was not contested, as it would simplify the wording... and the committee likes wording to be as simple as possible :)

Comment: I suspect `Effects: Sets memory_­rsrc to r.` might be the relevant clause.  By taking the argument by-pointer rather than by-reference, the API encourages the programmer to think more carefully about object-lifetime issues regarding the passed-in object.  In particular, when calling a function/method that takes an argument by-reference, programmers who didn't read the documentation carefully (read:  most of us ;) ) would likely not expect that function to retain a pointer to the passed-in object for later use after the call has returned.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[N3916](http://wg21.link/n3916):

> Note that the memory-resource library is designed so that the `ShoppingList` constructor accepts a *pointer* to a `memory_resource` rather than a *reference* to a `memory_resource`.  It was noted that one common practice is to use references rather than pointers in situations where a null pointer is out of contract.  However, there is a more compelling practice of avoiding constructors that take objects by reference and store their addresses. We also want to avoid passing non-const references, as that, too, is usually considered bad practice (except in overloaded operators).

Comment: I really don't understand why the second practice is preferred. I would understand why they have chosen pointer instead of reference, if it were defined what exactly to do when NULL pointer is passed. E.g. use get_default_resource as boost does, but it's a non-standard extension. But in this case they introduced a possibility for *undefined behavior* when NULL pointer is passed just because they wanted to fulfill some good practice. For me it's nonsense. Now a user must read the documentation and understand that NULL is simply not allowed, or he will just get undefined behavior.